# Write the output of time, and the command it was timing, as a single line

Tags: bash, cmake

I am trying to time how long each file in my codebase takes to compile.

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33357776/955273), you can write a script which does times the actual compilation and then stores the results in a file

**`/tmp/time-build`:**

```
#!/bin/bash
{ time g++ "$@"; } 2> >(cat <(echo "g++ $@") - >> /tmp/results.txt)
```

You can then override `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` when calling cmake so that make uses the script to perform the compilation

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/tmp/time-build
make
```

This works as advertised, and yields results similar to the following:

```
real    0m1.190s
user    0m1.044s
sys     0m0.140s
g++ -Werror -Wall -Wextra ... /src/test/foo.cpp
```

However, to ease processing, I would like to store only the `real` time, and have it **on the same line** as the g++ command.

**Question:**

My command line fu is not up to the task of turning this:

```
{ time g++ "$@"; } 2> >(cat <(echo "g++ $@") - >> /tmp/results.txt)
```

Into a command which captures only the `real` output of time, and includes it along with the `echo "g++ $@"` on a single line.

I don't know what the `>(cat <(` and `) -` parts of the above command mean, and my attempts to incorporate a `grep real` and `echo` have failed

How can I do that?

Alternately, if there is a more idiomatic way to get cmake to output timings for each file processed, that too would be ideal.

Comment: Add a bit of `sed` trickery inlined?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you suggest some?

Comment: Well, my sed fu is just a bit rusty now ;-). Did you spot the [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962285/cmake-compilation-statistics) question?

Comment: If you already use CMake, I recommend you use ninja instead of make (with `-G Ninja`), which outputs compilation times into `.ninja_log` file.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, that is the question I linked to in this one, and the comment on the answer I referred to is from me! No answer there yet, so hence this question

Comment: @Steve Ah, sorry I didn't spot the link (was my 1st google result). Nevertheless piping the result of `time` to `sed` should do what you want according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112469/delete-specific-line-numbers-from-a-text-file-using-sed) easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best way to get compile times for a CMake-based project is to use [`ninja`](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html) instead of `make`.

To do this you have to specify ninja generator while configuring:

```
cmake -G Ninja <...>
```

Then build using ninja:

```
ninja
```

After that, look at the file called `.ninja_log`. First column is start time in milliseconds, second is end time, forth is target name and the last one is a hash of the command line used.

There are even some solutions for viewing and analyzing this log: [ninjatracing](https://github.com/nico/ninjatracing) converts `.ninja_log` to a format readable by Chrome's tracing tool.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out!

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd=(clang "$@")
{ time "${cmd[@]}"; } 2> >( tee >( real=$(grep -Po 'real\K.*'); echo "${cmd[*]} $real" >>result.txt ) )
```